# CakePHP model sets primary key to false upon creation

Tags: php, cakephp, datasource

I have created a new Datasource with CakePHP for a dynamoDB table.
Creating, Deleting and Updating work find except the array returned upon creation from the Model.

The **primary key** in my table is named **device_id** and this is what I get when I create a new entry:

```
$dataReturned = $deviceInfosModel->save($data, true, array_keys($data));
debug($dataReturned);

array(
    'DeviceInfos' => array(
        'device_id' => false,
        'shop_id' => 123,
        'user_id' => 1234,
    )
)
```

The entry is well created though but the primary key is always set to false in the array which is returned. I started to dig into cakePHP's code and found out that in the Model there is a line which sets the primary key to false upon creation.
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1857
My primary key is randomly generated with a unique hash.

Is there a way to avoid that? I would appreciate any tips.

The dynamoDB table is as follow:

name: device_infos
primary id 'device_id' (string), user_id, shop_id

And the model looks as such:

```
<?php

class DeviceInfos extends AppModel {

    public $useDbConfig = 'deviceInfos';

    public $useTable = 'device_infos';

    public $primaryKey = 'device_id';

    protected $_schema = array(
        'device_id' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'key' => 'primary',
            'length' => 128,
        ),
        'user_id' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
            'length' => 255,
        ),
        'shop_id' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
        ),
        'timestamp' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
        ),
        'timestampRange' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Is the random hash set for primary key field set in the data array you passing to save? If so that most likely won't work since CakePHP 's ORM only supports auto increment and uuid primary keys. Instead try generating the primary key hash in your datasource and set Model->id in datasource's `create()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I set the model id to the key in the create() method as suggested and it's working now.